# Index column based on condition

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a column that will count or add an integer to a suburb and for the same suburb that have different regions the values should be different.
My table looks like this:

```
Region|suburb
GC    |Brooklyn
ER    |Brooklyn
GC    |Brooklyn
GC    |Mountain View
GC    |Lynnwood
```

Expected results

```
   Region |suburb        |int
    GC    |Brooklyn      |1
    ER    |Brooklyn      |2
    GC    |Brooklyn      |1
    GC    |Mountain View |3
    GC    |Lynnwood      |4
```

Bear in mind there's over a thousand suburbs so it wouldnt be practical to to use a case statement.

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? You could use `ROW_NUMBER` with the `OVER` clause. Look up SQL Window functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Sean - not just SQL Server. It's been part of the standard since at least as far back as 2003 and many RDBMS systems have now implemented it.

Comment: Why do you need two same rows in a table?
"GC    |Brooklyn      |1" and 
"GC    |Brooklyn      |1"

Comment: @PavelSmirnov the dataset has order numbers too

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `rank()`:

```
select region, suburb,
       rank() over (partition by suburb order by region) as num
from t;
```

This enumerates the suburbs in alphabetical order by region.  That is not exactly the results in your example, but it is consistent with the question you are asking.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Good catch.  The OP seems to want `rank()`.  The requirement (in the text) is that the values be different for the combination.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here:

```
Region|suburb
_______________
GC    |Brooklyn
ER    |Brooklyn
GC    |Brooklyn
GC    |Mountain View
GC    |Lynnwood
```

Can be normalised to an new table with unique Reqion and suburb fields like so:

```
Id|Region|Suburb
__________________
1 |GC    |Brooklyn
2 |ER    |Brooklyn
3 |GC    |Mountain View
4 |GC    |Lynnwood
```

See how the duplicate GC-Brooklyn entry is not there?

Then use this new table's Id in you existing table ( from which you have removed the Region and Suburb field. Like so:

```
ColumnA |ColumnB |RegionSuburbId
________________________________
Foo1    |Bar1    |3
Ipsum   |Factum  |1
Loony   |Tunes   |4
Acme    |Anvil   |1
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM OtshepengDitshego
INNER JOIN RegionSuburb on HorseNoName.RegionSuburbId = RegionSuburb.Id
```

would give you

```
ColumnA |ColumnB |RegionSuburbId |ID |Region|Suburb
____________________________________________________
Foo1    |Bar1    |3              | 3 |GC    |Mountain View
Ipsum   |Factum  |1              | 1 |GC    |Brooklyn
Loony   |Tunes   |4              | 4 |GC    |Lynnwood
Acme    |Anvil   |1              | 1 |GC    |Brooklyn
```